# Deletion of uploaded images

Tags: apache

I got this error
when I tried to delete an image which I have uploaded:

> "Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /act-photo-delete.php on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request:

> Apache/2.2.11 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.8i DAV/2 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 Server at www.friendsjoint.com Port 80 "

What will be the reason for this?

I tried changing the chmods for the files,
but nothing worked.

Does any one have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It is a file not found error. Are you sure you have provided the correct path for the php file.

For the forbidden part take a look at this.

[Forbidden – You don’t have permission to access this page error and solution](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-access/)